# ServiceFabric Local Cluster SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, localhost, kestrel, azure-service-fabric

I have some misunderstanding with running SF on local cluster with SSL, on localhost.
Microsoft created [greate article about configuring HTTPS on your endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint) But it works well only **if you use their certificate generator** `CertSetup.ps1` . If you try install your own pfx, it will not work.

**First** I created localhost self-signed cert by OpenSSL:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=W:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
openssl genrsa -out W:\CERTS\wepapissl.key -passout pass:1234567890 -aes256 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -key W:\CERTS\wepapissl.key -days 10000 -out W:\CERTS\wepapissl.crt -passin pass:1234567890 -subj /CN="localhost"
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey W:\CERTS\wepapissl.key -in W:\CERTS\wepapissl.crt -out W:\CERTS\wepapissl.pfx -passout pass:0987654321 -passin pass:1234567890`
```

**Second** I have created default ASP.NET Core Web Application (Core 2.0, API template). And added code for configure Kestrel to use HTTPS:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(opt =>
            {
                opt.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(GetCertificateFromStore());
                });
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore()
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=localhost", false);
            return currentCerts.Count == 0 ? null : currentCerts[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have got expected result. Page with warning about website’s security certificate:
[Result from ValueController with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiahL.png)

**Third** I have created Service Fabric Application (Stateless ASP.NET Core template). Change my `ServiceManifest.xml` by editing `Endpoint` section:

```
<Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8256" />
```

And added code for configure Kestrel to use HTTPS (`class Web1 : StatelessService`):

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder()
                                .UseKestrel(opt =>
                                {
                                    int port = serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint").Port;
                                    opt.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port, listenOptions => 
                                    {
                                        listenOptions.UseHttps(this.GetCertificateFromStore());
                                    });
                                })
                                .ConfigureServices(
                                    services => services
                                        .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                }))
        };
    }

    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore()
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=localhost", false);
            return currentCerts.Count == 0 ? null : currentCerts[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Result**: Successful build and deploy code on local SF cluster. [But my resource can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWO8m.png)

P.S. I will repeat again, if you install new cert by using PowerShell provided by Mircosoft - `CertSetup.ps1`, it works well for SF application. I was trying to dig in PS script, but I can not understand what I missed.

P.P.S I am new in creating certificates, but it seems strange.

1. I have installed pfx by `CertSetup.ps1`. **All works well** (resource is reachable).
2. Then I have exported cert to pfx with *private key* and *all extended properties*
3. Delete from LocalMachine (MY and Root), CurrentUser (MY) stores
4. Install exported pfx to LocalMachine (My and Root), CurrentUser (My) stores
5. Rebuild & Redeploy code
6. Resoucre can not be reached

Is it magic? Or I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Couple details was not enough clear for me, any way. Answer:
If you tried to use your own generated certificate (openssl, makecert or etc), you shoud set privileges for NETWORK SERVICE.

`To manually do this on your dev box, open up certlm.msc, expand Personal->Certificates, and right-click your cert. Select All Tasks->Manage private keys and then add NETWORK SERVICE.`

More here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/714#issuecomment-381281701